# Botão print - no chrome não aparece as imagens

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Usei o código acima, porém no `chrome` ele não aparece as imagens que estão dentro da área de impressão, no `mozilla` aparece.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: qual "código acima"?

Comment: Bem vinda, http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: edite sua pergunta e poste o "código acima"